# Correct scope for multi threaded batch jobs in spring

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-tasklet

I believe I've got a scoping issue here.

**Project explanation:**

The goal is to process any incoming file (on disk), including meta data (which is stored in an SQL database). For this I have two tasklets (FileReservation and FileProcessorTask) which are the steps in the overarching "worker" jobs. They wait for an event to start their work. There are several threads dealing with jobs for concurrency. The **FileReservation** tasklet sends the *fileId* to **FileProcessorTask** using the job context.

A separate job (which runs indefinitely) checks for new file meta data records in the database and upon discovering new records "wakes up" the FileReservationTask tasklets using a published event.

With the current configuration the second step in a job can receive a null message when the FileReservation tasklets are awoken.

If you uncomment the code in **BatchConfiguration** you'll see that it works when we have separate instances of the beans.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polling a folder for new files is not suitable for a batch job. So using a Spring Batch job ([filePollingJob](https://github.com/ben467834/spring-batch-project-01/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/config/BatchConfiguration.java#L196)) is not a good idea IMO.

> Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Polling a folder for new files and running a job for each incoming file is a common use case, which can be implemented using a `java.nio.file.WatchService` or a `FileInboundChannelAdapter` from Spring integration. See [How do I kickoff a batch job when input file arrives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49986860/how-do-i-kickoff-a-batch-job-when-input-file-arrives) for more details.

Comment: As an alternative to spring integration You can use 'Apache Camel' file endpoint to pick a file and then spring-batch to process it.